# If a man masturbate just to stimulate his sex drive and to get pleasure (e.g by touching his nipples), will it be considered haraam?

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

Salam,

Masturbation is haraam, I know. But scholars says it haraam by judging only the ejaculation of sperm. But is it haraam if a man do it without ejuculating  sperm by touching his nipples and daydreaming only because he can't control himself? Thank you.

Comment: It's all in the intention, you're intentions are to serve your sexual desires regardless of if you do it to the point of ejaculation.

Answer (score 0):

Masturbation is always done to stimulate sex drive or pleasure. And no matter how it is done it is forbidden. The proper alternative is marriage.